# How can I pass a video file as parameter/arguement from android java class to an OpenCV native class?

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, image-processing

I am developing an image processing application. In my app, the user can choose a video file from the gallery. Since it is easier to use c++ in image processing, I would like to pass the video file path from my main class to an opencv native class (that can generate an h and cpp file). But how can I pass the video file path as parameter and arguement? I stored the file path into a string. Please help.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695232/using-native-functions-in-android-with-opencv) It may help

Comment: I checked that link but I still don't know what to do with my code :(